# input box inside jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

How to get value entered in jQuery Input Box When Clicking on Save button of jquery dialog box.

```
window.parent.$('#divDialog')
  .attr('title', 'Edit ATM Details')
  .html('<table><tr align="center"><td align="center">Enter ATM ID &nbsp;</td><td align="center"><input id="txtEditATM" name="txtEditATM" type="text" /></td></tr></table>')
  .dialog({
     buttons: {
              "Save": function() {
                                 var atmid = $('#txtEditATM').val();
                                 //Next Processing Done Here
                                 }
              }
   });
```

Comment: Apart from the leading `window.parent.` part this looks OK.  What's your actual problem?

Comment: you have already got the value! `var atmid = $('#txtEditATM').val();`

Comment: alert(atmid); prints "undefined"

Comment: Test `var atmid = window.parent.$('#txtEditATM').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is also in window parent, so you should:

`var atmid = window.parent.$('#txtEditATM').val();`

Answer (score 0):

I'd break it up, makes it easier to read and controls your context easier

```
var div = window.parent.$('#divDialog');
        div.attr('title', 'Edit ATM Details').html('<table><tr align="center"><td align="center">Enter ATM ID &nbsp;</td><td align="center"><input id="txtEditATM" name="txtEditATM" type="text" /></td></tr></table>');

        div.dialog({
             buttons: {
                      "Save": function() {
                                         var atmid = div.find('#txtEditATM').val();
                                         //Next Processing Done Here
                                         }
                      }
            });
```